# How to handle (a lot) timers in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer

My situation is the following: People connect to my server and my server does store some information about the users which connected. For each connected user I have to handle 3 events on different times. So I thought about how to handle this is a good way. I had 2 different approaches in mind.

- Creating a timer for each users event and that's it. Then my callback will be fired when it's time
- Storing the timestamps on which the events should  get fired and going through these timestamps every second and check if something need to get called

Which way would be the better to do this? Is there a general approach how to deal with scenarios like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any reason to think that node won't handle the timers well? Definitely your first approach should be #1 -- use a timer for each event.

If for some reason that won't work then use a heap of timers. The root of the heap is always the closest timer to expire, and when that expires you go thru the heap, handling *all* the timers that expired (there may be more than 1), and then set a single timer to the next expiry time.

Comment: I don't know any reason why it shouldn't work I just wanted to ask if I should think more detailed about this before starting

Comment: Well, my recommendation stands, then :)